# How does Amanda reassemble partial level0 backups from different dates?

Tags: backup

It would appear that Amanda does a portion of a level0 of the specified disklist for every run.

Let's presume that the incremental backups for a dump cycle do not exist or are destroyed (perhaps by running every run with noinc?)

It would appear that for a dumpcycle you have a series of partial level0 backups created at different dates.

How does amrecover explain what the state of the data if it is made up of partials from different dates?

Presumably, you just have to accept that a dumpcycle's level0 comprises files from different dates?

http://www.backupcentral.com/wiki/index.php/AMANDA

In this example it happens that the total size of the disklist is split for each run by directory. However, it would appear that in reality Amanda generates the partial level0 based on the entire size of the disklist, so presumably a partial level0 is in fact a partial set of files comprising total size/runcycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is: Full backups are spread out to keep each day's backup size down. The daily backup includes both a partial full backup and incremental merged together to avoid duplicate files.

The use case: A single 200GB daily tape to backup 500GB of storage with 10-20Gb changed or added each day. With a 4 day cycle it works. No need for a larger tape, a tape library or manually configuring partial full backups.

Damaged or missing incremental leaves you with a spread out full backup which could be useless depending on what the files are for - not everything accepts a possible mix of old and new files.

Comment: So my understanding was correct in that it generates partial full backs from various dates? How does the recover executable present this to the user?

Comment: Don't think of the incremental as separate from the partial full backup. Combined they mean a full backup is present on the set of backup media on the last day of the cycle. Changes since the first day to the partial full backups are captured by the incremental.